# How to fix an "overlap" or collision between multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, display

When I connect my Samsung SyncMaster SA300 to my laptop running Windows 7 64 bit, I get a weird behavior.

When the lid is closed, everything seems to work:

[image]

When the lid is open, there is a weird collision between the monitors. Only one monitor is identified, and it seems to be a "merge" of the two monitors.

[image]

I installed the latest drivers from Samsung's site and ran Windows update. What is causing this, and how to fix?

**Update** - now the screen is dark with a "check signal cable" box. The cable is connected, and nothing I do (reinstalling driver and playing with monitor's internal config didn't seem to fix it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking **Windows-P** and extending the desktop to the other monitor helped with the 'check signal cable'. I always forget to try this (even though it was right there in the Screen Resolution settings!).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your video card software to configure your view? usually ATI and Nvida have their own application that allows you configure your view and resolution etc... try using that instead of the windows version maybe that would correct this problem of yours.

Comment: Please see the answer I posted - the problem is solved now.